# Let ($X_{i} , i \in I$) be family of disjoint topological spaces, where each of them weight $\alpha$

Tags: general-topology

Let ($X_{i} , i \in I$) be family of disjoint topological spaces, where each of them weight $\alpha$ and assume that on $X = \bigcup(X_{i})_{i \in I}$ we have a weak topology. If the card($I$) $\leq \aleph_{0}$ prove that then $ \omega (X) = \alpha $.

If $\alpha$ is greater then $ \aleph_{0}$ it is not hard to show that this is true. But, when I tried to show it for $\alpha$ which is less then $ \aleph_{0}$ I got stuck.

I've put the base of X $B  = \bigcup(B_{i})_{i \in I} $ , where $B_{i}$ is base for $X_{i}$. It seems to me that that is the base with smallest cardinal number for X (because all $X_{i}$ are disjunct). Is that thinking correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is false if you allow $w(X_i)$ to be finite. If $X_i$ is a Sierpinski space (so weight is $2$) and we have $n$ (some finite number) many disjoint copies of that space, then $w(X)=2n$ not $2$ as you claim. In fact, in general we have in this disjoint sum situation that

$$w(X) = \sup_{i \in I} w(X_i) \cdot |I|$$

because we can do no better (to have a base for $X$) than taking a minimal base in each component.